# yocto targeting Armv7 processor, mount /usr

Tags: linux, mount

the main partition lacks space , for debugging purpose I need to build some stuff in debug configuration , so I need to move the **/usr/bin**, **/usr/lib** to another partition with more space
can it be done?
how to do it ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.